# F# function to be used in c# library : delegate with byref type

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I have a c# dll library with one method `g` accepting the following function `f` in C# as an input

```
 void f(double[] x, ref double func, double[] grad, object obj)
```

In the function body, both `func` and `grad` values are updated. The input signature of `g(f)` in F# reads

```
f:float[]-> byref<float> -> float[]-> obj->unit
```

how can I write `f` in f# to use `g(f)` in f#?

**EDIT** when I follow ildjarn's answer below like

```
let f(x:float[]) (func:byref<float>) (grad:float[]) (obj: obj) = 
    func <- ...
    grad.[0] <- ... 
    grad.[1] <- ...
    ...
    ()
```

I got error on `g(f)` with

> This function value is being used to construct a delegate type whose signature includes a byref argument. You must use an explicit lambda expression taking 4 arguments.

what should I do to make it work? thanks.
**UPDATE:**  it turns out I have to use `g(fun (x:float[]) (func:byref<float>) (grad:float[]) (obj: obj) -> ...`. Cannot give the inside function a name like `f`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, the function you've shown there uses curried syntax, mine uses tupled syntax -- these are entirely different function signatures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ml
let function1 (x:double[], func:byref<double>, grad:double[], obj:obj) = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A canonical way to expose F# functions to other .NET language is to use a class, sometimes a static class, e.g. the design of the LChart library ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2010/02/17/lchart-displaying-charts-in-f-part-i.aspx)):

[Excel Financial functions for .NET](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FinancialFunctions) is a project written in F#, and is a general .NET library. You can see how its public API is written. You can also learn how to link the FSharp.Core.dll to the dll so that the target machine does not need to install F# runtimes.

**Update:**

`ref double func` is translated to f# as `let y = ref (func)`, `double[] grad` is just `float[]` in F#. See the following example for the `ref`:

```
public class tt
{
    public static void temp(int x, ref double[] y)
    {
        y = new double[10];
        y[1] = 10;
    }
}
```

in F#:

```
    let y = ref (Array.create 10 0.0)
    tt.temp(0, y)
    printfn "%A" y
    0
```

Notice that the second parameter of `temp` is a `ref` type. You simply create a ref handle for the array object by using `ref` operator in F#.

Comment: I saw in your blog, you used system.func to wrap f# functions to feed in ms solver dll library. My question could be a similar case I guess. I was trying to use minasa in alglib from f#, but confused on the API signature in a f# context.